# How to scope by_month from belongs_to associated model?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, date, scope

```
ShiftNote belongs_to Shift has_many ShiftNote
```

I want to have scope `ShiftNote.by_month("2013-10")`

How to implement that?

Right now I am trying:

```
ShiftNote.includes(:shift)
          .where("shifts.starts_at <= ? AND shifts.starts_at >= ?", "2013-10-01".to_date, "2013-10-30".to_date)
```

But I get

> > > ShiftNote.includes(:shift).where("shifts.starts_at <= ? AND shifts.starts_at >= ?", "2013-10-01".to_date, "2013-10-30".to_date)
> > >       DEPRECATION WARNING: It looks like you are eager loading table(s) (one
> > >       of: shift_notes, shifts) that are referenced in a string SQL
> > >       snippet. For example:
>
> ```
> Post.includes(:comments).where("comments.title = 'foo'")
> ```
>
> Currently, Active Record recognizes the table in the string, and knows
>   to JOIN the comments table to the query, rather than loading comments
>   in a separate query. However, doing this without writing a full-blown
>   SQL parser is inherently flawed. Since we don't want to write an SQL
>   parser, we are removing this functionality. From now on, you must
>   explicitly tell Active Record when you are referencing a table from a
>   string:
>
> ```
> Post.includes(:comments).where("comments.title = 'foo'").references(:comments)
> ```
>
> If you don't rely on implicit join references you can disable the
>   feature entirely by setting
>   `config.active_record.disable_implicit_join_references = true`.    SQL
>   (1.6ms)  SELECT `shift_notes`.`id` AS t0_r0, `shift_notes`.`state` AS
>   t0_r1, `shift_notes`.`user_id` AS t0_r2, `shift_days`.`shift_id` AS
>   t0_r3, `shift_notes`.`created_at` AS t0_r4, `shift_notes`.`updated_at`
>   AS t0_r5, `shifts`.`id` AS t1_r0, `shifts`.`starts_at` AS t1_r1,
>   `shifts`.`ends_at` AS t1_r2, `shifts`.`rate` AS t1_r3,
>   `shifts`.`limit` AS t1_r4, `shifts`.`created_at` AS t1_r5,
>   `shifts`.`updated_at` AS t1_r6, `shifts`.`state` AS t1_r7,
>   `shifts`.`shift_notes_count` AS t1_r8 FROM `shift_notes` LEFT OUTER
>   JOIN `shifts` ON `shifts`.`id` = `shift_notes`.`shift_id` WHERE
>   (shifts.starts_at <= '2013-10-01' AND shifts.starts_at >=
>   '2013-10-30')

Comment: `ShiftNote.joins(:shift).where(shifts: { starts_at: ("2013-10-01".to_date.."2013-10-30".to_date) })` should do it (switched from includes to joins since you are doing a condition on the joined/included table)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `BETWEEN` query, which is achieved using a range of dates:

```
class ShiftNote < ActiveRecord::Base
  scope :by_month, ->(year = Date.today.year, month = Date.today.month) do
    first_day = Date.new(year, month, 1)
    last_day = Date.new(year, month + 1, 1) - 1
    joins(:shifts)
    .where('shifts.starts_at' => first_day..last_day)
  end
```

Comment: You need to change joins to :shift

Comment: I don't think it would be idiomatic :). No seriously, ActiveRecord infers the name of the table from the pluralization.